# sourcing a file containing env variables from ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I have the following snippet of code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

source /users/some_user/.cshrc
```

However, running this gives the `source:  not found` error.

I have also tried using the `dot` operator like:

```
#!/bin/ksh

. /users/some_user/.cshrc
```

However, this does not fix the issue either, though it no longer gives me the `source: not found` error.

What is the correct way to source the `.cshrc` file?

Comment: from `ksh`? Assuming it is really `csh` format in the `.cshrc`, you'd have to write a filter to convert the csh syntax to ksh. you're better off having 2 versions of the same .rc file, 1 that is csh syntax and the other ksh syntax. ELSE edut your question abouve to include some of the code that is in .cshrc file. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read a file in `ksh`, the `.` (dot) command is correct.  Only `bash` adds the `source` command borrowed from `csh`, but it is a wordy synonym for `.`.

Your residual problem is that the file that is to be read should be a `ksh` file, not a `csh` file — the notations in a C shell file (such as `setenv`) are quite different from those used in the POSIX shells (`bash`, `ksh`, etc).  Thus, you're facing a difficult task.

One (messy!) way to deal with the problem is:

```
$ exec csh
% source /users/some_user/.cshrc
% exec ksh
$ ...continue with the environment set by the .cshrc file...
```

The disadvantage of this is that the `exec` operations have to be hand-executed (or, at least, it is hard to do it programmatically).  The alternative is to translate the `.cshrc` file into `ksh` notation (using `export VAR=value` instead of `setenv VAR value`, etc).

If you want to automate it, translating the `.cshrc` file is likely the best way to go.

---

#### Ultra-simplistic conversion from `csh` to `ksh`

As a very crude, simplistic starting point, consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    next if m/^#/;
    chomp;
    if (m/^\s* setenv \s+ (\w+) \s+ (.+) $/x)
    {
        my($var, $val) = ($1, $2);
        $val = "\"$val\"" unless $val =~ m/^"/;
        print "export $var=$val\n";
    }
}
```

Given a `.cshrc` file containing:

```
# comment

setenv VAR value
setenv VAR_2 "value with spaces"
```

The output is:

```
export VAR="value"
export VAR_2="value with spaces"
```

This is unlikely to be sufficient, but it may be a sufficient start to get you going.

Comment: See also [tripleee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18217542/15168) for a intriguing alternative.  I created a simple `setenv() { export "$1"="$2"; }` and used `. cshrc` to get the VAR and VAR_2 values set correctly.  This won't help if there are other C shell operations, especially conditional operations, in the `.cshrc` file, but that's a limitation for the outline Perl script too.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a bunch of `setenv` calls, you could define your own ksh function.

```
setenv () {
    export "$1"="$2"
}

. /users/some_user/.cshrc
```

Comment: Interesting...could you compress that to: `export "$1"="$2"`?  The `eval` shouldn't be necessary, should it?

Comment: I guess you're right; thanks for the feedback! Updated accordingly.

Comment: I like what you've done — I've referenced it in a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

```
file /users/some_user/.cshrc
```

to confirm the file is where you think it is.
The dot operator *will* execute the file.

Putting an echo statement in the .cshrc will show that it has been run.

Be aware that `source` can't work, as it gets confused by the fact its a *csh* not a *ksh* script.

Also   [read this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/79640-calling-csh-script-ksh-shell.html)

Answer (score 0):

It works with the dot operator for me :

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ ksh
$ cat l
foo=bar
$ . /tmp/l
$ echo $foo
bar
```

my ksh version :

```
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
echo $KSH_VERSION
@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2
```

Like already said, you can't source a [csh](/questions/tagged/csh) file. To transform the csh file in ksh, you can test this sed command :

```
sed -rn '/setenv/{s@^\s*setenv\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)@export \1=\2@;p}' /users/some_user/.cshrc |
    tee /users/some_user/.kshrc_env_file
```